# Configure LDAP with PGAdmin

Tags: ldap, pgadmin, apache-directory

Trying to configure LDAP with pgAdmin.

I have pgAdmin running locally on a cluster and I'm using Apache Directory Studio as a local LDAP server with the default connection and I've created 1 user.

The logs from Apache Directory Studio are:

```
#!SEARCH REQUEST (462) OK
#!CONNECTION ldap://0.0.0.0:10389
#!DATE 2021-03-12T09:33:38.565
# LDAP URL     : ldap://0.0.0.0:10389/uid=admin,ou=system?*??(objectClass=*)
# command line : ldapsearch -H ldap://0.0.0.0:10389 -x -D "uid=admin,ou=system" -W -b "uid=admin,ou=system" -s base -a always "(objectClass=*)" "*"
# baseObject   : uid=admin,ou=system
# scope        : baseObject (0)
# derefAliases : derefAlways (3)
# sizeLimit    : 0
# timeLimit    : 0
# typesOnly    : False
# filter       : (objectClass=*)
# attributes   : *

#!SEARCH RESULT DONE (462) OK
#!CONNECTION ldap://0.0.0.0:10389
#!DATE 2021-03-12T09:33:38.566
# numEntries : 1
```

In my [pgAdmin config_local.py](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/5.0/enabling_ldap_authentication.html#) file I have the following:

```
AUTHENTICATION_SOURCES = ['ldap','internal']
LDAP_SERVER_URI = 'ldap://<my-ip-address>:10389'
LDAP_USERNAME_ATTRIBUTE = 'uid'
LDAP_BASE_DN = 'uid=admin,ou=system'
LDAP_SEARCH_BASE_DN = 'uid=admin,ou=system'
```

When I try to log into pgAdmin with admin or the created user I get the following error:

```
ldap3.core.exceptions.LDAPBindError: automatic bind not successful - invalidCredentials
```

I think I'm getting the base DN wrong or Apache isn't configured properly. Grateful for any help.

Comment: You need to provide binding credentials (`LDAP_BIND_USER` and `LDAP_BIND_PASSWORD`, equivalent of ldapsearch -D and -W options which we can see in the "command line" section of the logs output), or set `LDAP_ANONYMOUS_BIND` to true otherwise. Also it seems you are not using any domain components (or your base dn settings are wrong), @see what does a typical ldap [DIT](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Directory%20Information%20Tree) looks like.

Comment: Thanks for replying. So I've set  LDAP_ANONYMOUS_BIND to true as suggested. Still not able to log into pgAdmin but not getting any binding errors now. This in the POD log when I try to login into pgAdmin. `"POST /authenticate/login HTTP/1.1" 302 209 "http://127.0.0.1:8080/login?next=%2F" ` Will check out your link. I'm basically just testing LDAP with pgAdmin with an offline LDAP provider before we hit live services.

Comment: ..so if anonymous binding fails it means you must provide binding credentials using `LDAP_BIND_USER` and `LDAP_BIND_PASSWORD`.

Comment: Tried as you suggested. I initially set the `LDAP_BIND_USER` DN incorrectly and I would get an error saying `automatic bind not successful - invalidCredentials` On fixing it the bind error is not longer there but I just get the `"POST /authenticate/login HTTP/1.1" 302 225 "http://127.0.0.1:8080/login?next=%2Fbrowser%2F"` again

Comment: So I found the issue - Chrome pop-up blocker was stopping a pop-up from Apache Directory Studio asking you to allow connections. It worked first time. So I did have have it working with binding as a pgadmin user, as an anon user and now as a dedicated user. Thanks for your time @EricLavault its appreciated.